# How to delete image from image directory after delete record in codeIgniter Framework?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, image-uploading

I want to delete one or more product category form tbl_category.

- Where category_id,category_name,...... ,category_image   these are
  database field.
- My problem is that when I delete the Item then it completely delete 
  from the database but this image still stay into the directory

  i,e  base_url.'./images/category_images/'.

  How can I do It? help needed.

This is code for controller:

```
      public function manage_product_category()
    {
        $data=array();
        $data['all_product_category']=  $this->ehome_model-  >select_all_product_category();
        $data['admin_maincontent']=$this->load->view('admin/view_product_category',$data,true);
        $this->load->view('admin/admin_master',$data);   
    }
    public function delete_product_category($category_id)
    {
        $this->super_a_model->delete_product_category_by_category_id($category_id);
        redirect('super_admin/manage_product_category');
    }
```

This code for model:

```
     public function delete_product_category_by_category_id($category_id)
    {
        $this->db->where('category_id',$category_id);
        $this->db->delete('tbl_category');
    }
```

Comment: Please format your post to exclude regular text from codeblocks. Only code should go in codeblocks.

Comment: before redirect... you can get the data from db (before deleting), and unset the file on your web space

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the unlink php method: http://php.net/manual/it/function.unlink.php

```
$path = base_url.'./images/category_images/'.$file_name;
unlink($path);
```

Make sure to set the correct `$file_name`, if you do not have it, just run a query to your db to get the file name **before** to delete the row.

Comment: Dear  christian giupponi                                                              where do i write your code. Either controller or model please help.

Comment: In the controller, before to delete the category

Answer (score 0):

check this link
[click here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html).

```
$this->load->helper("file");
delete_files($path);
```

Comment: Dear parth  Where do I write your code . Either controller or model .

Comment: in controller add method

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must have a img_url field or any according to your requirement in your table.Then in first step you need to get that img_url from your table like then remove this from the directory like this,

```
//write this function in your_controller
function delete($your_id)
    {
        $img_url = $this->your_model->get_image_url($your_id);//this will get the img_url from your_ model 
        unlink($img_url);   //this will delete the image from your directory

        $this->your_model->delete_image_record($your_id); //this will delete the record from the table

    }
//write the following functions in your_model
function get_image_url($your_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('your_img_url');
        $this->db->from('your_table');
        $this->db->where('your_id',(int)$your_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() == 1) return $query->row()->your_img_url;
        else return NULL;

    }
function delete_image_record($your_id)
    {
        $this->db->where("$your_id",(int)$your_id);
        $this->db->delete('your_table');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller place this code.You need to get path of image from table which are going to be deleted.

```
$path_url = $this->your_model->get_path_url($your_id); 
if($path_url != NULL) 
{
    unlink($path_url ); //this will delete the image first.
    $this->your_model->delete_image_record($your_id);

}
```

And leave your model as it is just write this one extra function.The following function will retrieve the image path.

```
function get_path_url($your_id)
{
  $this->db->select('path_url');
  $this->db->from('your_table');
  $this->db->where('table_id',$your_id);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  if($query->num_rows() == 1) return $query->row()->path_url;
  else return NULL;
}
```